# Manipulate vertex of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have this code:

```
Ind = 10; StrategiesCop = {"1DD", "1CD", "2DD", "2DC"};Populations = UndirectedGraph[Flatten[Table[i -> j, {i, 2, Ind}, {j, i - 1}]], 
VertexLabels -> Thread[Table[i, {i, 1, Ind}] -> 
 PadRight[StrategiesCop, Ind, StrategiesCop]]]
```

[image]

Then I want to make the list of `EdgeWeight` with the next conditions:

1. The `EdgeWeight`  between same labels is `v+(1-v)f` where `f` is the frequency of label, in example : `1DD-1DD -> v+(1-v)0.3`
2. `v` is a parametre that I can change
3. The `EdgeWeight`  between different labels is `(1-v)`

Can I make a adjacency matrix and then the lists of `EdgeWeight`? o How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a graph after `EdgeWeight` is constructed.

```
Ind = 10; StrategiesCop = {"1DD", "1CD", "2DD", "2DC"};
nodeLabel = 
  Thread[Table[i, {i, 1, Ind}] -> 
     PadRight[StrategiesCop, Ind, StrategiesCop]] // Association;
f = nodeLabel // Tally //  MapAt[ #/Ind &, {All, 2}] // 
    Map[  Apply[Rule]] // Association;
allPairs = Subsets[Range[Ind], {2}];
grouped = 
  allPairs // 
   GroupBy[  nodeLabel[# [[1 ]]] == nodeLabel[# [[2 ]]] &];
edges = grouped // Values // Catenate;
edgeWeight[v_] = Join[
   ConstantArray[ 1 - v, Length@grouped[False]]
   , grouped[True]  // Map[ (1 - v) f[ nodeLabel[# [[1 ]]]] + v &]
   ];

UndirectedGraph[ edges , EdgeWeight -> edgeWeight[v], 
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> Normal@nodeLabel]
```

[image]